# Problema con color de consola

Tags: c++

He tenido el siguiente problema con mi código

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;
int Factorial (int cantidad) {
    int valor;
    for (int i=1; i<=cantidad; i++){
        valor *= i;
    }
    return valor;
}
main () {
    int z;
    z = Factorial(4);
    cout << "El resultado es " << z ;
    getch ();
}
```

El cual me arroja un valor correcto, sin embargo al intentar darle color a la consola.

De la siguiente manera, me arroja un valor errado.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;
int Factorial (int cantidad) {
    int valor;
    for (int i=1; i<=cantidad; i++){
        valor *= i;
    }
    return valor;
}
main () {
    system ("color f0");
    int z;
    z = Factorial(4);
    cout << "El resultado es " << z ;
    getch ();
}
```

Existe algún problema de sintaxis o es un problema tal vez del compilador?

Comment: El estándar de C++ no contempla características de color para la consola, luego la solución dependerá de si vas a usar Windows o Linux, incluso en el caso de Linux es probable que la solución dependa de la distribución en concreto que estés usando.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mira primero que todo tienes que inicializar la variable valor para que el factorial te devuelva un resultado viable

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;
int Factorial (int cantidad) {
int valor = 1;
for (int i=1; i<=cantidad; i++){
    valor *= i;
}
return valor;
}
int main () {
system ("color f0");
int z;
z = Factorial(4);
cout << "El resultado es " << z ;
getch();
return 0; 
}
```

Y con respecto a lo del color se cambia satisfactoriamente te dejo una imagen para que veas es un gris... Si necesitas aclarar algo mas me lo pones en los comentarios... Considera siempre inicializar las variables aunque sean globales...Salu2

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]